# Google maps API using arrival time with traffic duration

Tags: json, xml, google-maps, google-api, google-distancematrix-api

The Google Maps API docs as well as all questions I have found on Stack Overflow all state that departure time must be included to return traffic duration. However, my application requires the use of arrival time and not departure time.

The docs state that one can pass either departure or arrival time, but this is not mentioned in relation to duration_in_traffic. Is it possible to pass arrival time instead of departure time and still receive the duration_in_traffic? Maps itself does this, I don't see a reason for Google's API to be any different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but there is a [long-standing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35829984) to have this feature added. You can star the issue to receive updates and show Google that there is additional interest.